# Cannot Change Strategy of Configuration SQLite

Tags: sqlite, gradle

In my Gradle project, I have a dependency for SQLite.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
 import groovy.sql.Sql

    buildscript {
        ext{
            osPackageVersion = "3.4.0"
            kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
            requery_version = '1.5.1'
            sqlite_jdbc = '3.7.2'
            rxkotlin_version = '2.2.0'
            sqlDirPath = "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "Resources" + File.separator + "TestAppDbInit.sql"
        }

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            maven{
                url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath "edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:2.4.4"
            classpath group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta-extensions', version: '3.11.2'
            classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.11.2'
            classpath 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
        }
    }

    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '3.0.1'
    }

    group 'org.wycliffeassociates.translationrecorder'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    configurations {
        sqllite
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifac/'}
        maven { url  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed" }
        maven { url  "https://dl.bintray.com/dua3/public" }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.16"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

        compile "com.github.thomasnield:rxkotlinfx:2.2.2"
        compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$rxkotlin_version"

        compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.11.2'
        compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: "$sqlite_jdbc"
        jooqRuntime group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta-extensions', version: '3.11.2'
        jooqRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
        sqllite 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
        kapt "io.requery:requery-processor:$requery_version"

        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0"
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'

        implementation 'com.github.WycliffeAssociates:8woc2018-common:dev-SNAPSHOT'
        compile 'com.github.WycliffeAssociates:jdenticon-kotlin:-SNAPSHOT'

        compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:9.1.2-jpms'
        compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-9.1.2-jpms'
        compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-icons525:4.2.0-9.1.2-jpms'
        compile 'com.github.afester.FranzXaver:Examples:0.1'
        compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.5' // Java 8

        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+"
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.+'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.+'
        testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.+'
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }


    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
    configurations.sqllite.each { File file ->
        loader.addURL(file.toURL())
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
```

I try to run the build for the project, and I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':sqllite' after it has been resolved.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.preventIllegalMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultCachePolicy.eachModule(DefaultCachePolicy.java:161)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultCachePolicy.cacheChangingModulesFor(DefaultCachePolicy.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultResolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor(DefaultResolutionStrategy.java:190)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultResolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor(DefaultResolutionStrategy.java:186)
        at org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy$cacheChangingModulesFor.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_2rl70kyg6ax354v7xbsnpa8n1$_run_closure8.doCall(C:\Users\dipinton\8woc2018-jvm\build.gradle:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:158)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_2rl70kyg6ax354v7xbsnpa8n1.run(C:\Users\dipinton\8woc2018-jvm\build.gradle:113)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 99 more
```

It's my impression that this error I'm receiving has to do with the fact that I have 2 configurations blocks. One for configuring my SQLite module, and another for handling the resolution strategy of all modules. These two closures seem to be conflicting with one another.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remove the conflict between these two closures?

Answer (score 1):

This working with addUrl on the copy of configuration:

```
def sqliteCopy = configurations.sqlite.copy()
sqliteCopy.each {File file -> 
    loader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())
}
```

instead of:

```
configurations.sqllite.each { File file ->
        loader.addURL(file.toURL())
    }
```

or downgrade *com.android.tools.build:gradle* to 3.1.4 version.